# Clunking noise disappears when weather is cold?

Tags: mazda, noise

On my '02 Mazda Protege5, I hear a clunking noise on the front, driver side wheel area. I am lead to believe that it is a Control Arm Bushing.

Anyway, it was really bad this past summer and persisted until now that it's mid November and temperature is hovering a little above 0 Celcius. It's like my car got fixed.

Is this a case of rubber expands / metal contracts when cooled?

Comment: That's what I'd put my money on. You could possibly put this vehicle in a warm garage for a long period of time (a couple of hours) to test your theory. The clunking would return for a little while until things got cold again (at 0C, it wouldn't be warm for long, though). Ultimately, vehicles *very rarely* fix themselves (almost never, but I don't deal with absolutes).